# Writing structs to a socket

Tags: c, struct, padding

So I have some structs containing data that I want to send to another process using a unix socket. This process may not be compiled using the same compiler version, or even be written in C for that matter. This is the struct (note that some stuff is commented out):

```
struct nested_struct {
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint16_t c;
} */__attribute__((packed))*/;

struct my_struct {
    uint32_t num_nested_structs;

    /* uint8_t padding[3];*/
    uint8_t   x;
    uint16_t  y;
    uint16_t  z;

    struct nested_struct nested[];
} /*__attribute__((packed))*/;
```

For convenience and performance, I'd like to get away with something like

`write(socket, &data.x, data.num_nested_structs * sizeof(struct nested_struct) + 5)`

or something -- but I doubt this would be safe, given that `struct my_struct` is not nicely aligned. But how about if we un-comment the packed attribute? This feels like it should work, but I've read that referencing fields in `__packed__` structs by address can be dangerous.

What if we instead uncomment the `uint8_t padding[3];` field? Now both structs are word size-aligned (on a system with `WORD_BIT = 32`). Is it safe to assume that the compiler won't add any padding in this case? If so, is this enough to ensure that accessing `5 + 4*num_nested_structs` bytes of memory starting from `&my_struct.x` is safe?

Comment: It's generally not safe to write binary data between machines, since they may have different representations, alignments, endiness, etc. You should use a serialization library, such as JSON, XML, or XDR.

Comment: This is a unix socket for inter process communication.

Comment: Another reason to consider some form of serialization, is "slack" space within your structures.  The two different compilers/languages may have different "native" slack space (if at all) in the structure... and would may need some type of pragma (or their version of a pragma) to eliminate slack space.  Additionally, some of your variables are "unsigned", which older versions of Java do not have as native primitive data types.

Comment: When using uint8_t or uint32_t, __attribute__((packed)) is not dangerous. Since your both sides (client and server) will map the correct memory size.